# Can't connect to Postgres DB through Apache Tomcat?

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, jdbc-postgres

I'm trying to set up Geoportal 1.2.4, running on Apache Tomcat 8.5.6, Postgres 9.0.6_1, JDK 6, and jdbc(postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar). I cannot log into the Geoportal, When I log in using admin details (),I
get this error
"A database communication error has occurred"
Checking the Apache logfiles, I see there's a severe error

[image]

I have tried a range of different entries in the config for the jdbc, but it always comes back to that error.

That is just my latest attempt. I have seen conflicting posts all over the net about exactly what the url should look like.
I checked the rest of the config files carefully, and the editing within them was minimal and probably has no play on the error.
If anyone could point out my mistake it would be appreciated.

Comment: The 9.1 driver is extremely outdated. Try [the current driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) which is 42.2.10 - it should work with your outdated Postgres 9.0

Comment: Postgres 9.0 has been [unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) for over 4 years now. You should plan an upgrade to the current version now.

Comment: I am working on a legacy code and the version specified are those. I used it to build the system. I will change the jdbc driver to the latest one and will check. Thank you

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you very much...... It worked !!!! If you post your comment as answer, I will accept it else i can write it down has answer. cheers.